# how to add number group wise when group occurs more than one continuously using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1    col2
 12       A
 14       A
 22       B
 24       C
 20       A
 18       B
 16       B
```

Now I want to add the values of col1 on the basis of col2 if col2 value occurs more than one time continuously. The final data frame should look like:

```
col1    col2
 A       26
 B       22
 C       24
 A       20
 B       34
```

I can use groupby() but how to differentiate continuous conditions ?

Comment: Why have `col1` and `col2` been swapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with helper `Series` created by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
s = df['col2'].ne(df['col2'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(s).agg({'col2':'first', 'col1':'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  col2  col1
0    A    26
1    B    22
2    C    24
3    A    20
4    B    34
```